# Ставить ли запятую после деепричастного оборота в данном случае?

Tags: пунктуация, деепричастный-оборот

"Именно используя акрил художник может наиболее широко раскрыть все возможности живописи".

Если запятая не нужна, то по какому правилу?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кратко, то да ***запятая нужна***, как при всяком сколько-нибудь развернутом деепричастном обороте.

А если разбираться, то какие есть мотивы отказаться от неё? Да, передаваемое деепричастием действие тесно связано со сказуемым и используется в значении причины и/или образа действия. Другими словами, по функции близко к наречию. Но вся беда в том, что все эти соображения крайне редко применяются иначе как применительно к одиночным причастиям. Когда есть хотя бы одно "зависимое" слово (используя ***акрил***), деепричастие порождает деепричастный оборот. А для него все эти мотивы явно недостаточны. Даже если интонационно там этой запятой совсем не чувствуется, она положена в силу грамматики.

Comment: Большое спасибо, Behemothus, Вы как раз поняли смысл моего вопроса! Именно ощущение того, что деепр. оборот здесь фактически теряет свое глагольную функцию, будучи используемым в значении "именно при помощи", и сподвигло меня на этот вопрос! :-)

Comment: Никакой "тесной связи со сказуемым" здесь и близко нет, дорогой @behemothus. По большому счету заслужили вы минус, да ладно уж...

Comment: Спасибо за мнение. Когда оно будет более аргументированным, возможно, оно будет интересным мне более, чем ваши разговоры о минусах, которые вы не знаете, за что бы поставить. )))

Answer (score 2):

**Именно используя акрил**, художник может наиболее широко раскрыть все возможности живописи.

Частица "именно" входит в состав обособленного деепричастного оборота. Отметим, что на интонацию предложения (наличие паузы при обособлении оборота) частица не оказывает влияния.

Правила на тему

Деепричастные обороты **обособляются в большинстве случаев**, исключения из этого правила рассматриваются отдельно.

К деепричастиям могут быть отнесены частицы и союзы (союзные слова), которые **обособляются вместе с деепричастными оборотами**, не отделяясь от них запятыми: Она сидела молча, только слегка улыбаясь.

**Исключение**: Можно прожить **и не хвастая умом**, без этих  разговоров.К деепричастному обороту может относиться союз И с усилительным значением; в этом случае деепричастие имеет значение наречия, является обстоятельством образа действия и не обособляется.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ, Sibylla! Но меня волновало, не относится ли рассматриваемый мною случай к т.н. исключениям, поскольку я ощущал потерю глагольной функции деепр. оборотом в рассматриваемом случае, да и интонационно не чувствовал паузы.